# jQuery manipulate DOM on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I want to change hidden inputs value to `true` or `false` when link is clicked.

```
<a href="#" class="open-advanced-search">Advanced search</a>

advanced_search = $('.advanced-search-block .hidden-block')
advanced_search_field = $('#payment_search_advanced_search')

$('.open-advanced-search').on 'click', ->
  if '#help needed here'
    $(advanced_search).show()
    $(advanced_search_field).attr('value', 'true')
  else
    $(advanced_search).hide()
    $(advanced_search_field).attr('value', 'false')
  return
return
```

I know that there's a method `toggle` but that's enough for me, as i also want to update html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `if ... else`, you can do both show/hide and true/false switches in one block, like this:

```
$(advanced_search).toggle()
$(advanced_search_field).attr('value', $(advanced_search).is(':visible'))
```

The first line toggles visibility on and off. The second line will then read out whether it is now visible, if so, the result is `true` else `false`.